# Display placeholder text inside HTML textbox in old version of html

Tags: html, input, vbscript, textbox, placeholder

I need to display placeholder text inside of a textbox (like "password"). Were using a really old version of internet explorer, maybe 5.5? No javascript, only VBScript. Not using HTML5 I think, placeholder doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholders are not working on Internet Explorer 9 and earlier.

Comment: So is there no way to do this? I'm not married to the placeholder tag itself, I just want the label for the textbx display inside the box when its empty

Comment: Yes, and this is called a placeholder, and to my knowledge, there is no way to do that on IE9 or earlier. On the other hand, it works for IE10.

Comment: our app is old af, just wraps around IE 5.5 i think. Def not up to IE 8 yet

Comment: You can't upgrade it to IE10 ? Because IE5.5 is old now ahah! You're welcome.

Comment: nah im just a lowly intern. were just reskinning the ui